# Create Outlook Calendar through .net application

Tags: .net, web-services, outlook

Is it possible to create a shared calendar in Outlook programmatically through a WebService, I am looking for behaviour similar to the calendar integration in SharePoint?

The calendar would need to be read only and would not need to reflect changes back to the WebService (at this time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we ended up going with was publishing to SharePoint calendar and having outlook sync to that and the our software synced to/with the sharepoint calendar.

**edit**: if we were doing this again we would use the Exchange Web Services managed API and just setup a shared calendar in exchange, then have our application sync to that.